# In VSCode: why the inputs and outputs are shown alternatively even though pasting inputs in bulk

Tags: input, visual-studio-code, terminal, output

Here is my code. A simple one. Get inputs 5 times then print 5 of them.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("%d\n",a+b);
  }
  return 0;
}
/*
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
*/
```

Then I try to input all inputs at once. (Paste the inputs in bulk)
Then below was what turns out.

```
1 2
3
3 4
7
5 6
11
7 8
15
9 10
19
```

The inputs and outputs are shown alternatively!

[image]

> There is one more '3' between the first line and second line.

What I am looking for is as below.

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
3
7
11
15
19
```

How do I do this? I try to go through every setting in vscode but none of them seems to solve the problem... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs and read your outputs, not critique your use of color and perspective.

Comment: Alright, let me edit the post

Comment: Where did you paste the text?

Comment: In the terminal